# Positioning figures

Tags: tables, floats, positioning

I want to force a table and a figure to appear in a page with nothing except them. I've tried `\clearpage` but it makes lots of extra spaces in the document. Also some of the figs appear in the end of the document although I have placed them in the middle of the document.

This is the code I'm using :

```
\begin{figure*}[ht]
{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pic1}}\caption{example_fig} 
\label{fig1}
\end{figure*}

\begin{table*}[ht]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\hsize=0.8\hsize}X *2{>{\hsize=1.1\hsize}X}@{}}
a & b & c \\[0.7ex]
\end{tabularx}
\caption{example}
\label{tab:template}
\end{table*}
```

So if anyone could please assist me.

Comment: Add the `p` placement option, which is for a page with floats only: `\begin{figure*}[pth]`. Personally, I would never use `h` but use the default: `pth`.

Comment: @user1460166 If they are on different pages then LaTeX thinks they do not fit on the same page, you could use `[!p]`  to make it less fussy but (as has been said before) it is hard to give exact advice without a working example that shows the problem.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen please post your comment as an answer to mark it as the solution to my problem

Comment: @user1460166 The question is some form of duplicate of some other. I don't want to take credit for it.